# How to include PlantUML in Asciidoc with Antora?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, antora

I would like to inlcude a **PlantUML** file inside an **Asciidoc** file and build an **Antora** site.

**foo.adoc**

```
[plantuml, bar, svg]
....
include::bar.puml[]
....
```

**bar.puml**

```
@startuml
<... valid PlantUML>
@enduml
```

The PlantUML does show up correctly inside my IDE (IntelliJ).

### Problem

When i run `antora antora-playbook.yml`, i get the following error:

```bash
ERROR (asciidoctor): target of include not found: bar.puml
    file: /$PROJECT_PATH/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/foo.adoc:11
    source: /$PROJECT_PATH (branch: #branch-name <worktree> | start path: docs)
Skipping plantuml block. GET https://kroki.io/plantuml/svg/<image-id> - server returns an empty response or a 404 status code
```

Everything works fine if i use inline PlantUML instead of an `include` statement.

### Update

I've already tried to use the following Antora Resource ID's:

- `include::page$bar.puml[]`
- `include::ROOT:page$bar.puml[]`
- `include::ProjectName:ROOT:page$bar.puml[]`
- `include::{docdir}/bar.puml[]`

The error message remains the same: `target of include not found: ...`

My project structure looks like this:

```
- modules
  - antora.yml
  - antora-playbook.yml
  - ROOT
    - pages
      - foo.adoc
      - bar.puml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause is: `ERROR (asciidoctor): target of include not found: bar.puml`.
When working with Antora, you should reference a resource using an Antora resource ID: https://docs.antora.org/antora/latest/page/resource-id/

```
[plantuml, bar, svg]
....
include::example$bar.puml[]
....
```

https://docs.antora.org/antora/latest/page/include-an-example/

Comment: Thx. I've added an update to th question regarding your answer.

Comment: you should create an `examples` directory next to `pages` and move "bar.puml" in it. Then, use `include::example$bar.puml[]`.
The `pages` directory is reserved for AsciiDoc files.

Comment: Thank you very much. After creating an `examples` directory under `ROOT` and putting the puml file there, i was able to include it and build the antora site successfully.